# emulater.exe not working in windows 7 32 bit

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android. Recently when i m running my android app I got error of emulator.exe has stopped working I searched on internet I got various solution i used all but still my emulator is crash at the time of start
 **have tried all the following options suggested by them:

**Change the RAM value - I have tried with all values ranging from 256 to 1907**

**Change the target - Have tried the versions from 4.1.2, 4.2.2, 4.2 along with their Google APIs**

**Change the device - Have tried with various versions of Nexus along with WSVGA**

**Change the Heap - Have tried with different values of Heap size**

**Change the resolution - Have tried with various resolutions as per the device****

please anyone help me

Comment: I guess you've tried just about everything ... but telling us the error message it fails with.  PLEASE POST THE ERROR MESSAGE!!!!!!

Comment: error message is:"Emulater.exe has stopped working"
No error On console and Logcat

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry the message wasn't meaningful - but glad you looked, and glad you knew *where* to look :)  SUGGESTION: Try `emulator -avd MY_AVD -debug-all` from the command prompt.  ALSO: Q: what is your OS? 16 or 32 bit?  Which version of the Android SDK/which version of emulator.exe (`emulator -version`) are you using?